# How would I be able to remove opposite values (e.g. refunds) in panel data?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Given the following data:

```
id|datee      | price | quant | discrete_x
 1 2018-12-19      4    -3000   A
 1 2018-12-04      4     3000   A
 1 2018-12-21      4     3000   B
 1 2018-12-20      3     2000   A
...
```

Desired output:

```
id|datee      | price | quant | discrete_x
 1 2018-12-21      4     3000   B
 1 2018-12-20      3     2000   A
...
```

In this case, it is quite clear that the quantity (`quant`) of 3000 is refunded, then bought again. I would like to remove the two rows for cancelling each other out. Given that `id` and `quant` match while the refund happens *once and after* a purchase of matching number of `quant`, how would I be able to remove all of them for each `id` value?

I've been considering (but stuck on) two ideas so far:
1) Within an arranged `group_by` values, check the later dates within a column to see if `quant` would match as opposite values
2) For loop within a for loop

I feel that for loop within a for loop is better, but not sure how I would match on `discrete_x`.

How would your approach be? Would you use for loop within a for loop?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the desired output, it isn't clear from the post.

Comment: @caldwellst Sorry, added!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution will work for your problem.

```
df <- abs(df$quant)
df1 <- df[!duplicated(df[c("id","quant")]),]
```

assuming your data frame name is df.

Comment: That won't work. Ideal solution would remove it once, and only after the a purchase date of equivalent quant.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very ugly implementation, but I think this might work. We can create a filtering column after grouping by `id` and arranging by `date`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(datee) %>%
  mutate(f = lead(quant) + quant == 0,
         f = ifelse(f, f, lag(f)),
         f = tidyr::replace_na(f, FALSE)) %>%
  filter(!f) %>%
  select(-f)

#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#> # Groups:   id [1]
#>      id datee      price quant discrete_x    
#>   <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1 2018-12-20     3  2000 A
#> 2     1 2018-12-21     4  3000 B
```

Comment: I'm feel that I'm understanding most of it, but does this mean that this only removes the purchase only if it's one row index before? If there were more purchases between the refund and the refunded purchase, it would not get rid of it, correct?

Comment: Yeah, was going off this statement from your original post: "1) Within an arranged group_by values, check the row below within a column to see if quant"

Comment: Ah oops, I fixed it to "later dates" instead. However, it seems that even just up to `mutate(f = lead(quant) + quant == 0)` will crash it due to using too much memory even after reducing it to only 7 variables. :(