# R: Is there a way to search for a nearly identical row?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

This is my original problem: [How would I be able to remove opposite values (e.g. refunds) in panel data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753716/how-would-i-be-able-to-remove-opposite-values-e-g-refunds-in-panel-data)

Given the following data:

```
id|datee      | price | quant | discrete_x
 1 2018-12-19      4    -3000   A
 1 2018-12-04      4     3000   A
 1 2018-12-21      4     3000   B
 1 2018-12-20      3     2000   A
...
```

this is my desired output:

```
id|datee      | price | quant | discrete_x
 1 2018-12-21      4     3000   B
 1 2018-12-20      3     2000   A
...
```

The two removed rows are identical except for date and quant. Is there a way to match two different rows for certain variables?

Another requirement would be to make sure that the negative quant comes after the matching row date-wise. Ideally, it would also be the latest date before the negative quant observation.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(h=T,text="
           id datee      price  quant  discrete_x
 1 '2018-12-19'      4    -3000   A
 1 '2018-12-04'      4     3000   A
 1 '2018-12-21'      4     3000   B
 1 '2018-12-20'      3     2000   A")
```

Comment: What you want is an aggregation by id, price,  and discrete_x, but the rule isn't clear to me. do you want the latest value in that case ? better to be explicit than give us only the expected input and let us infer the rule.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Yes, latest value would be ideal!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id, discrete_x) %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>      id datee      price quant discrete_x
#>   <int> <fct>      <int> <int> <fct>     
#> 1     1 2018-12-20     3  2000 A         
#> 2     1 2018-12-21     4  3000 B
```